# Isochronous USB transfers confusion

Tags: linux, usb

1. Isochronous endpoints are one way only. But single isochronous IN transmission is described in various sources (eg. here http://www.beyondlogic.org/usbnutshell/usb4.shtml#Isochronous) as one IN token packet (from host to a device) followed by one DATA packet (from a device to the host). So I see communication in both directions here. Is the token packet from the host *received* by the same IN isochronous endpoint which then *sends* the data?
2. What is synchronization for? HERE : http://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus#Supporting_Isochronous_Transfers we read : "Due to application-specific sampling rates, different hardware clock designs, scheduling policies in the operating system, or even physical anomalies, the host and isochronous device could fall out of synchronization." But how? I understand the sequence of events like this : device fills its outgoing buffer with data, and waits for the token (some interrupt probably). Host sends the token packet, and waits for the data packet, which (I think) should arrive instantly. Sequence is repeated every frame (@F.S.) and everybody is happy. Isn't the token packet synchronizing the reply from the device?
3. Here http://wiki.osdev.org/Universal_Serial_Bus#SYNC_Field we read : "All USB packets start with a SYNC field which serves, unsurprisingly, as a synchronization mechanism between the receiver and the sender." So once again I ask : why to synchronize isochronous transfers in another manner than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. All USB transactions are always initiated by the Host. E.g. for an isochronous IN transaction the Host will ask the device for the next piece of data first. This is of course a data flow to the device, but on a lower protocol level (Token Packets). So a kind of control data is send TO the device, but the meaningful data (Data Packts) is only sent FROM the device (IN direction). When you develop software for a device you can often abstract away the Bus Protocol details, because they are handled in hardware (USB device peripheral). The low level messages do not enter an endpoint. Endpoints are on a higher layer.
2. Consider a USB microphone: It records audio data with a very specific sample rate which is based on the local oscillator of the device. It's only a matter of time that the clock of the Host and the microphone will drift. After a few minutes a gap in the data would appear (or a buffer overflow will occur) because the microphone is recording data at a slightly different speed then the USB is expecting it (from the device's configuration descriptor). So they need some kind of synchronization.
3. The SYNC field is on the lowest Layer. It is for bit synchronization only and should not be confused with the synchronization for isochronous endpoints (2.)

You might want to take a look at the official [USB 2.0 Specification](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/usb_20_070113.zip) (usb_20.pdf) instead of all the third party wikis which kind of confused you.